# How to print out bootstrap menu?

Tags: theming

I am using the [Bootstrap module](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap). In the code I can see this:

```
<?php if (!empty($primary_nav) || !empty($secondary_nav) || !empty($page['navigation'])): ?>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <nav role="navigation">
                <?php if (!empty($primary_nav)): ?>
                    <?php print render($primary_nav); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if (!empty($secondary_nav)): ?>
                    <?php print render($secondary_nav); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if (!empty($page['navigation'])): ?>
                    <?php print render($page['navigation']); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </nav>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

The problem is, I can't get it to print it for any other menu. For example, i created a menu called "web design menu". I am able to make it appear as follows:

```
print drupal_render(menu_tree_output(menu_tree_all_data('menu-web-design-menu')));
```

However, this doesn't give it the styling of bootstrap or any of the nice bootstrap benefits. How do I render it so that it renders it the same way the above code does. I.e. with all the correct bootstrap styling and executed javascript etc.

Comment: I take you are putting your line of code between <nav>?

Comment: I've tried it without nav as well.

Comment: Are you using both the primary and secondary menus? If not you can just reassign one of those in the menu admin and move them around in the template file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the boostrap theme there is a file

> theme/menu/menu-tree.func.php

This file contains a function

> bootstrap_menu_tree__primary

This function wraps the menu as following:

```
'<ul class="menu nav navbar-nav">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
```

So you have to give the wrapper of your menu those classes and make sure the structure is exactly the same as the primary menu.

Hope this helps you out.